# Unexpected result of multiset mapping in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, collections, oracle11g, multiset

Please help me to confirm is that behavior explained below is a bug, or clearly explain why it's right.
There are a high probability that I misunderstood some concept, but now for me it looks like a bug.

All examples below simplified as much as possible to demonstrate core of the issue. Real situation is very complex, so only general answers and workarounds related to principle of query construction is acceptable.
You are welcome to ask clarifying questions in comments and i'll try to do my best to answer them.
Thank you for attention. :)

### Question

Why in last Example (Example 5) `collection` instance in  `(select count(1) ...` subquery from first row mapped to all rows of the table, while expected result is to map each `collection` instance to it's own row?
At the same time `collections` used in `cardinality(...)` expression chosen properly.
Same situation (not covered in examples) exists if constructed in this way collections used in `from` or `where` part of a query.

### Test schema setup

([SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ea363/50))

```
create or replace type TabType0 as table of varchar2(100)
/

create table Table0( tab_str_field varchar2(100), tab_field TabType0)
nested table tab_field store as tab_field_table
/

insert into table0 (tab_str_field, tab_field) values (
   'A',
   cast(multiset(
     select 'A' from dual union all
     select 'B' from dual union all
     select 'C' from dual 
   ) as TabType0) 
)
/

insert into table0 (tab_str_field, tab_field) values (
   'B',
   cast(multiset(
     select 'B' from dual union all
     select 'C' from dual 
   ) as TabType0) 
)
/

insert into table0 (tab_str_field, tab_field) values (
   'C',
   cast(multiset(
     select 'A' from dual union all
     select 'B' from dual union all
     select 'C' from dual union all
     select 'D' from dual 
   ) as TabType0) 
)
/

insert into table0 (tab_str_field, tab_field) values (
   'D',
   cast(multiset(
     select 'A' from dual 
   ) as TabType0) 
)
/
select 'Initial table data' caption from dual
/
select * from table0
/
```

table data:

```
| TAB_STR_FIELD | TAB_FIELD |
-----------------------------
|             A |     A,B,C |
|             B |       B,C |
|             C |   A,B,C,D |
|             D |         A |
```

### Examples

**Example 1** ([SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ea363/49))  - work with nested table fields - **OK**

```
select 'Work with nested table - OK' caption from dual
/
select 
  tab_field                               tab_field,

  -- cardinality
  cardinality(tab_field)                  tab_cardinality,

  -- select from table field of current row
  (select count(1) from table(tab_field)) tab_count,

  -- select from field of current row while joining 
  -- with another field of same row
  ( select column_value from table(tab_field) 
    where column_value = tab_str_field
  )                                       same_value
from table0
/
```

results:

```
| TAB_FIELD | TAB_CARDINALITY | TAB_COUNT | SAME_VALUE |
--------------------------------------------------------
|     A,B,C |               3 |         3 |          A |
|       B,C |               2 |         2 |          B |
|   A,B,C,D |               4 |         4 |          C |
|         A |               1 |         1 |     (null) |
```

**Example 2** ([SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ea363/51)) - work with constructed source data alone - **OK**

```
select 'Work with constructed source data alone - OK' caption from dual
/
with table_data_from_set as (
  select
    'A' tab_str_field,
    cast(multiset(
      select 'A' from dual union all
      select 'B' from dual union all
      select 'C' from dual
    ) as TabType0)  tab_field
  from dual union all
  select
    'B' tab_str_field,
    cast(multiset(
      select 'B' from dual union all
      select 'C' from dual
    ) as TabType0)  tab_field
  from dual union all
  select
    'C' tab_str_field,
    cast(multiset(
      select 'A' from dual union all
      select 'B' from dual union all
      select 'C' from dual union all
      select 'D' from dual
    ) as TabType0) tab_field
  from dual union all
  select
    'D' tab_str_field,
    cast(multiset(
      select 'A' from dual
    ) as TabType0) tab_field
  from dual
)
select
  tab_field                                tab_field,

  -- cardinality
  cardinality(tab_field)                   tab_cardinality,

  -- select from table field of current row
  (select count(1) from table(tab_field))  tab_count,

  -- select from field of current row while joining
  -- with another field of same row
  ( select column_value from table(tab_field)
    where column_value = tab_str_field
  )                                        same_value
from table_data_from_set
/
```

results:

```
| TAB_FIELD | TAB_CARDINALITY | TAB_COUNT | SAME_VALUE |
--------------------------------------------------------
|     A,B,C |               3 |         3 |          A |
|       B,C |               2 |         2 |          B |
|   A,B,C,D |               4 |         4 |          C |
|         A |               1 |         1 |     (null) |
```

**Example 3** ([SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ea363/52)) - join table with multisets constructed in `WITH` - **OK**

```
select 'Join table with multisets constructed in WITH - OK' caption from dual
/
with table_data_from_set as (
  select
    'A' tab_str_field,
    cast(multiset(
      select 'A' from dual union all
      select 'B' from dual union all
      select 'C' from dual
    ) as TabType0)  tab_field
  from dual union all
  select
    'B' tab_str_field,
    cast(multiset(
      select 'B' from dual union all
      select 'C' from dual
    ) as TabType0)  tab_field
  from dual union all
  select
    'C' tab_str_field,
    cast(multiset(
      select 'A' from dual union all
      select 'B' from dual union all
      select 'C' from dual union all
      select 'D' from dual
    ) as TabType0) tab_field
  from dual union all
  select
    'D' tab_str_field,
    cast(multiset(
      select 'A' from dual
    ) as TabType0) tab_field
  from dual
)
select
  table0.tab_field                                            table0_tab_field,
  table_data_from_set.tab_field                               set_tab_field,

  -- cardinality
  cardinality(table0.tab_field) table0_tab_cardinality,
  cardinality(table_data_from_set.tab_field)                  set_tab_cardinality,

  -- select from table field of current row
  (select count(1) from table(table_data_from_set.tab_field)) set_tab_count,

  -- select from field of current row while joining
  -- with another field of same row
  ( select column_value from table(table_data_from_set.tab_field)
    where column_value = table0.tab_str_field
  )                                                           same_value
from 
  table0, 
  table_data_from_set 
where 
  table_data_from_set.tab_str_field = table0.tab_str_field
/
```

results:

```
| TABLE0_TAB_FIELD | SET_TAB_FIELD | TABLE0_TAB_CARDINALITY | SET_TAB_CARDINALITY | SET_TAB_COUNT | SAME_VALUE |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|            A,B,C |         A,B,C |                      3 |                   3 |             3 |          A |
|              B,C |           B,C |                      2 |                   2 |             2 |          B |
|          A,B,C,D |       A,B,C,D |                      4 |                   4 |             4 |          C |
|                A |             A |                      1 |                   1 |             1 |     (null) |
```

**Example 4** ([SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ea363/53)) - join table with multisets constructed in WITH + subquery - **OK**

```
select 'Join table with multisets constructed in WITH and subquery - OK' caption from dual
/
with table_data_from_set as (
  select
    'A' tab_str_field,
    cast(multiset(
      select 'A' from dual union all
      select 'B' from dual union all
      select 'C' from dual
    ) as TabType0)  tab_field
  from dual union all
  select
    'B' tab_str_field,
    cast(multiset(
      select 'B' from dual union all
      select 'C' from dual
    ) as TabType0)  tab_field
  from dual union all
  select
    'C' tab_str_field,
    cast(multiset(
      select 'A' from dual union all
      select 'B' from dual union all
      select 'C' from dual union all
      select 'D' from dual
    ) as TabType0) tab_field
  from dual union all
  select
    'D' tab_str_field,
    cast(multiset(
      select 'A' from dual
    ) as TabType0) tab_field
  from dual
)
select
  table0_tab_field                            table0_tab_field,
  set_tab_field                               set_tab_field,

  -- cardinality
  cardinality(table0_tab_field)               table0_tab_cardinality,
  cardinality(set_tab_field)                  set_tab_cardinality,

  -- select from table field of current row
  (select count(1) from table(set_tab_field)) set_tab_count,

  -- select from field of current row while joining
  -- with another field of same row
  ( select column_value from table(set_tab_field)
    where column_value = table0_tab_str_field
  )                                           same_value
from (
  select 
    table0.tab_str_field              table0_tab_str_field,
    table0.tab_field                  table0_tab_field,
    table_data_from_set.tab_str_field set_tab_str_field,
    table_data_from_set.tab_field     set_tab_field
  from 
    table0, 
    table_data_from_set 
  where 
    table_data_from_set.tab_str_field = table0.tab_str_field
)
/
```

results:

```
| TABLE0_TAB_FIELD | SET_TAB_FIELD | TABLE0_TAB_CARDINALITY | SET_TAB_CARDINALITY | SET_TAB_COUNT | SAME_VALUE |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|            A,B,C |         A,B,C |                      3 |                   3 |             3 |          A |
|              B,C |           B,C |                      2 |                   2 |             2 |          B |
|          A,B,C,D |       A,B,C,D |                      4 |                   4 |             4 |          C |
|                A |             A |                      1 |                   1 |             1 |     (null) |
```

**Example 5** ([SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ea363/54)) - join table with multisets constructed on the fly - **FAILED**

```
select 'Join table with multisets constructed on the fly - FAIL (set_tab_count wrong)' caption from dual
/
with string_set as (
  select 'A' str_field from dual union all
  select 'B' str_field from dual union all
  select 'C' str_field from dual union all
  select 'D' str_field from dual union all
  select 'E' str_field from dual 
)
select
  table0_tab_field                            table0_tab_field,
  set_tab_field                               set_tab_field,

  -- cardinality
  cardinality(table0_tab_field)               table0_tab_cardinality,
  cardinality(set_tab_field)                  set_tab_cardinality,

  -- select from table field of current row
  (select count(1) from table(set_tab_field)) set_tab_count,

  -- select from field of current row while joining
  -- with another field of same row
  ( select column_value from table(set_tab_field)
    where column_value = table0_tab_str_field
  )                                            same_value
from (
  select 
    table0.tab_str_field     table0_tab_str_field,
    table0.tab_field         table0_tab_field,
    ( 
      cast(multiset(
        
        select 
          string_set.str_field 
        from 
          string_set, 
          table(table0.tab_field) tab_table
        where 
          string_set.str_field = tab_table.column_value
        
      ) as TabType0)
    )                        set_tab_field
  from 
    table0 
)  
/
```

result (all values in `set_tab_count` column are same - ***wrong!*** ) :

```
| TABLE0_TAB_FIELD | SET_TAB_FIELD | TABLE0_TAB_CARDINALITY | SET_TAB_CARDINALITY | SET_TAB_COUNT | SAME_VALUE |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|            A,B,C |         A,B,C |                      3 |                   3 |             3 |          A |
|              B,C |           B,C |                      2 |                   2 |             3 |          B |
|          A,B,C,D |       A,B,C,D |                      4 |                   4 |             3 |          C |
|                A |             A |                      1 |                   1 |             3 |     (null) |
```

### Oracle version information

**Instance 1**

```
BANNER
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.3.0 - 64bit Production
PL/SQL Release 11.2.0.3.0 - Production
CORE    11.2.0.3.0  Production
TNS for IBM/AIX RISC System/6000: Version 11.2.0.3.0 - Production
NLSRTL Version 11.2.0.3.0 - Production
```

**Instance 2**

```
BANNER 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - Production 
PL/SQL Release 11.2.0.2.0 - Production 
CORE    11.2.0.2.0  Production 
TNS for 32-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production 
NLSRTL Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production
```

[SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ea363/48) with all queries together.

Comment: This is so confusing. You're not doing a good job articulating what you're trying to do, what the expected results are, and what exactly is going wrong. All I know is that your results for `set_tab_count` in the last test aren't what you expected. I have no idea what this value is supposed to represent, and I'm not reading through all of this code. I appreciate that this might be the simplest you could boil down a reproducible test case, but if that' the case you need to explain your code some because we're not going to nitpick through it all.

Comment: @DavidMarx What kind of explanation do you need for understanding all above? First 4 examples demonstrates same results with different approach to use collections in joins. But fifth result broke all logic which can be seen in first 4 examples. I just want to understand logic in Example 5 or get reasonable explanation why it's a bug.

Comment: There are 2 more workaround suggested in reply to my question on OTN forum ( https://forums.oracle.com/thread/2550938 ) , but more specific than provided by @jonearles

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bug.  Adding a `/*+ NO_MERGE */` hint to the second inline view in the last example will generate the expected results.  See [this SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ea363/58) for an example.  Regardless of the query, that hint should never change the results.  There are a couple of other seemingly unrelated changes you can make that will generate the correct results, such as removing some of the columns, or adding an unused `ROWNUM` in the middle.

Oracle is re-writing your query to optimize it, but doing something wrong.  You could probably get some more information by tracing the query, but I doubt you'll be able to truly fix the issue.  Work around it for now and submit a service request to Oracle so they can create a bug and eventually fix it.

Comment: Nice done! Thank you very much for discovering workaround! I tried both workarounds on examples that fits my needs more closely (like that: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/12159/11 ) and found both working.