# Sorting variables in a record

Tags: sql, oracle, sorting

I have an Oracle table with multiple columns some populated with a variable, there a large number of possible variables, the example below is not exhaustive.

```
ID  Col1  Col2  Col3 
--------------------
1   A     B
2   B     A     D
3   B     C
4   C     B     
5   B     B
6   E     D   
7   B     A     C
```

I need to create a query that resorts the variables in each row:

```
ID  Col1  Col2  Col3 
--------------------
1   A     B
2   A     B     D
3   B     C
4   B     C     
5   B     B
6   D     E   
7   A     B     C
```

I am looking for an elegant solution as the real world problem has 20 columns with up to 40 different variables (up to four characters in length each) and several million records.

Comment: What have you tried? What errors you got? Show us some code. Also tag this in sql

Comment: How would we know which columns to reshuffle?  Does it have to be a query or can it be a stored procedure?

Comment: I haven't tested this solution, but this question seems to be trying to do the same thing: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12100566/sort-results-by-column-not-row

Comment: What is in fields that do not have a "variable": `space` or `NULL`?

Comment: Which cols to sort is a good question - I should have stated I think they would have to be specified eg col1, col2, col3 .. coln

Comment: Cols that are 'empty' have either null or ''.  I have been using TRIM(NVL(Coln,' ')) to get them all to the same ''.

Comment: I would be happy to use a stored procedure, I am not that familiar with them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is a variant for `Oracle 10g` and later. Because there are a big number of rows in original dataset I'll tried to avoid solutions which involves grouping and analytic functions atop of a full result set.

Base table for this example:

```
create table tab1 (
  ID   number,
  col1 varchar2(4), 
  col2 varchar2(4), 
  col3 varchar2(4), 
  col4 varchar2(4) 
)
```

First, collect all columns for each `ID` to sorted collection:

```
select
  tab1.ID,
  cast( multiset(
    select 
      decode(level,
        1, tab1.col1,
        2, tab1.col2,
        3, tab1.col3,
        4, tab1.col4,
        null
      )       
    from dual 
    connect by level <= 4
    order by 
      decode(level,
        1, tab1.col1,
        2, tab1.col2,
        3, tab1.col3,
        4, tab1.col4,
        null
      ) 
      nulls last          
  ) as sys.ODCIVarchar2List) sorted_values
from tab1;
```

Having such a dataset it's possible to decode values back to columns while maintaining specified order:

```
select
  ID,
  (
    select column_value 
    from table(data_list.sorted_values)
    where rownum = 1
  ) as col1,
  (
    select max(decode(rownum, 2, column_value, null))
    from table(data_list.sorted_values)
  ) as col2,
  (
    select max(decode(rownum, 3, column_value, null))
    from table(data_list.sorted_values)
  ) as col3,
  (
    select max(decode(rownum, 4, column_value, null))
    from table(data_list.sorted_values)
  ) as col4
from (
  select
    rownum,  -- this needed as workaround for Oracle bug
    tab1.ID,
    cast( multiset(
      select 
        decode(level,
          1, tab1.col1,
          2, tab1.col2,
          3, tab1.col3,
          4, tab1.col4,
          null
        )       
      from dual 
      connect by level <= 4
      order by 
        decode(level,
          1, tab1.col1,
          2, tab1.col2,
          3, tab1.col3,
          4, tab1.col4,
          null
        ) 
        nulls last          
    ) as sys.ODCIVarchar2List) sorted_values
  from tab1
) 
  data_list
```

**[<kbd>SQLFiddle test</kbd>](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/5958f/3)**

Note that `rownum` must be present in inner `select` clause as a workaround for [this Oracle error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17113299/unexpected-result-of-multiset-mapping-in-oracle-sql).

Comment: Wow that is a nice solution.  the SQLFiddle version works a treat.  I get Error code: 907 ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis when I run it in production on Oracle 11.2.0.2.0 any ideas what that might be - the code all looks fine...?

Comment: @user2798561 You tried to run exact code from example (e.g. through copy&paste) or already adapted it for your solution? Is it possible that you really missed a right bracket at some place? SQL Fiddle runs exactly 11.2.0.2.0 ([proof link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/1187)).